# using a cell from another sheet as reference

Tags: excel, excel-formula, reference, countif

[image]I wrote a formula which calculates the inputs in "Sheet2" which is below. So J4 is a cell of Sheet2:

```
=((COUNTIF((INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(J4);COLUMN(J4))&":J"& 
(MIN(IF(A4:A107="";ROW(A4:A107))))));" 
 <>"&""))-1)/((COUNTIF((INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(J4);COLUMN(J4))&":J"& 
(MIN(IF(A4:A107="";ROW(A4:A107))))));"<>0"))-1)
```

Now I want to write this formula to a cell in Sheet1.It means i should reference the Sheet2 for calculating the formula.

Can anyone help me with referencing?

EDIT: I still am without solution for this issue. Can anyone suggest me something new then in the comments?

Comment: You can reference cells from `Sheet2` in `Sheet1` by simply adding : **`Sheet2!`** in front of any cells that are in `Sheet2` (i.e. where you have `J4`, replace it with: **`Sheet2!J4`**.

Comment: i tried it but somehow formula does not work. `&":J"& 
(MIN(IF(A4:A107="";ROW(A4:A107))))));" ` should i also add Sheet2! to this parts as well? to ":J" and also A4:A7?

Comment: Yes. Any cells that you want to reference from `Sheet2` in `Sheet1` have to have `Sheet2!` infront of them. If it's a range in `Sheet2` then it would be something like: `Sheet2!A4:A107`

Comment: `=((COUNTIF((INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(Sheet2!J4);COLUMN(Sheet2!J4))&":Sheet2!J"& (MIN(IF(Sheet2!A4:A107="";ROW(Sheet2!A4:A107))))));"<>"&""))-1)` this gives me still #REF error

Comment: Can you provide sample of your `Sheet2`? I can then test your formula

Comment: should i send it you mean? is there chance to do so?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169331/discussion-between-soru-soravic-and-zac).

Comment: I cant seem to join that chat

Comment: same here now, can i send you the data somehow?

Comment: You can just add a sample of your sheet here (even if it's as a pic) I can then use your data to test the formula

Comment: i have added the picture of Sheet2 to the question:) Column i use the formula is K3 but i want to delete the column K and use this formula in my sheet1

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your formula, it seems you want to evaluate ratio of:

> Count non-blank cells in column J where column A is also non-blank.
>   Divide this count by count of non-zero cells in column J where column A is non-blank.

If yes then test following formula and see if it works per your needs:

`=COUNTIFS(Sheet2!A4:A107,"<>",Sheet2!J4:J107,"<>")/COUNTIFS(Sheet2!A4:A107,"<>",Sheet2!J4:J107,"<>0")`

Make sure you change argument separators.

**Edit**

In that case, you need to use following array formula (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>) and change argument separators.

`=COUNTIFS(Sheet2!A4:INDEX(Sheet2!A4:A107,MIN(IF(Sheet2!A4:A107="",ROW(Sheet2!A4:A107)))),"<>",Sheet2!J4:INDEX(Sheet2!J4:J107,MIN(IF(Sheet2!A4:A107="",ROW(Sheet2!A4:A107)))),"<>")/COUNTIFS(Sheet2!A4:INDEX(Sheet2!A4:A107,MIN(IF(Sheet2!A4:A107="",ROW(Sheet2!A4:A107)))),"<>",Sheet2!J4:INDEX(Sheet2!J4:J107,MIN(IF(Sheet2!A4:A107="",ROW(Sheet2!A4:A107)))),"<>0")`

Comment: This is not what i am looking for. **1) Divident:** I count non empty cells in column J from range **J4 to first row number where A has first empty cell(if A7 is first empty cell after A4 then I should search in range J4-J7)** **2)Divider** Amount of all cells(non blank and blank cells together) from **J4 to first row number where A has first empty cell**

Comment: @SoruSoravic see formula added for the described condition.

Comment: Formula calculates wrong values. My initial formula included "-1". Do you think i should add this to my formula? I can show you a sample if you need?

Comment: @SoruSoravic Indeed. Test by adding the '-1' part to formula.

Comment: as far as i see, there are two counf its one for divident one for divider. i added -1 for both sides but result is again not showing same as:    
`=((COUNTIF((INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(J4);COLUMN(J4))&":J"& 
(MIN(IF(A4:A107="";ROW(A4:A107))))));" 
 <>"&""))-1)/((COUNTIF((INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(J4);COLUMN(J4))&":J"& 
(MIN(IF(A4:A107="";ROW(A4:A107))))));"<>0"))-1)`

Comment: Please use `Formula evaluate` option to see the internal results and see where it is not giving intended results...