# empty string value if there is no date inside range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formulas

I have following formula which i add as a picture here in the question as well.

```
=MIN(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(AF4);COLUMN(AF4))&":af"& (MIN(IF(A4:A108="";ROW(A4:A108))))))
```

AF3 and AG3 columns should calculate the minimum date in dynamic range(based on empty cell in A). As you can see in AF, if all values are "N/A" formula brings automatically 00.01.1900 by default. I want it to return empty string if the range does not contain any date. If it has a date inside the range, the formula should work as it works in AG3.[image]

How can i do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [finding correct minimum date in a range specified in formula which may contain just string values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49893836/finding-correct-minimum-date-in-a-range-specified-in-formula-which-may-contain-j)

Comment: I feel like you're asking the same question everyday...

Comment: might be a duplicate because i did not get any response which helps me

Comment: Looks like you have custom date format implemented there. What happens if you use custom format `dd.mm.yyyy;"";""` in cell `AF3`.

Comment: i can use this for sure! how can i add this to my formula though?

Comment: Have you tried rewording your question so you get a helpful response rather than reposting it every day?

Comment: yes i did and i put even picture now, i do not know how i can explain my issue more clear then this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the formula in `IF` like below and test:

`=IF(MIN(AF4:INDEX(AF:AF,MIN(IF(A4:A108="",ROW(A4:A108)))))=0,"",MIN(AF4:INDEX(AF:AF,MIN(IF(A4:A108="",ROW(A4:A108))))))`

1. I have dropped `INDIRECT` which is volatile. Above construct is less volatile.
2. It is ARRAY formula so you need to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>.
3. Make sure you replace "," with ";" in formula arguments at your end.

Comment: Formula works great! thank you! one question regarding indirect. Will removing indirect from my formula and updating it with your version, will not cause any issues? i am asking this because i have many formulas which i use indirect. can i exchange it with this version then?

Comment: @SoruSoravic Yes. Test the results and then implement. Generally, volatile formula constructs shall be avoided. You can read some articles on Charles Williams' site http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsi.htm

Comment: thank you very much! appreciate it a lot! do you have any knowledge about how to reference from other sheets? assuming you have much knowledge in excel, can you check also following? [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49917511/using-a-cell-from-another-sheet-as-reference?noredirect=1#comment86888658_49917511

Comment: @SoruSoravic I have posted an answer there as well. See if it suits your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You could follow @shrivallabha redij's suggestion of a custom format or use a TEXT statement like this

```
=TEXT(MIN(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(AF4),COLUMN(AF4))&":af"& (MIN(IF(A4:A108="",ROW(A4:A108)))))),"dd.mm.yyyy;;")
```

EDIT

I agree with @shrivallabha's advice to use Index instead of Indirect. If I was doing this from scratch, I would also use Aggregate:

```
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,AF4:INDEX(AF4:AF108,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(A4:A108)/(A4:A108=""),1)),1),"")
```

Comment: it returns an empty string when there is no date so that part works. but when there is a date, it returned following: ""dd.00.yyyy" and the date should have been 01.03.2015

Comment: I think it's going to be a language or locale issue. You could try going into Format | Custom and see what it offers as the first date format. In my locale (UK) it's mm/dd/yyyy for instance.

Comment: i do not get it. it does not switch the month and date to each other, it just pastes mm.00.yyyy, if it would be format then it should have been 03.01.2015, no?

Comment: My guess is that it is treating mm as minutes (which would be zero) but not recognising dd and yyyy, it's fine on my system.